# ffmpeg avi xvid for Pyle Car Stereo

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been trying to transcode video files so they play on my Pyle PLDN74BTI car stereo.  I have some sample media of the twilight zone that plays just fine. I'm using ffmpeg -i to display the codec information and I'm trying to match those settings. But over 30 tries later and I'm still not getting it.

Here's what I'm trying to match (a file that works):

```
Input #0, avi, from 'The Twilight Zone Sea.1 Ep.9-Perchance To Dream.avi':
Metadata:
 encoder         : VirtualDubMod 1.5.10.1 (build 2366/release)
Duration: 00:24:49.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 911 kb/s
 Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (XVID / 

0x44495658), yuv420p, 496x368 [SAR 1:1 DAR 31:23], 837 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 64 kb/s
```

Here's the command line I have so far for ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i "Redman - Let's Get Dirty (I Can't Get In Da Club)-_b_zT6mdN3c.mp4"  -c:v mpeg4 -q:v 5 -vtag XVID -f avi -b 990k -bf 2 -g 300 -s 496x368 -pass 1 -an -threads 0  -y "31-redman.avi"
```

and here's the ffmpeg -i output on the file I create:

```
  encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:03:29.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1577 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 496x368 [SAR 92:93 DAR 4:3], 1573 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 24k tbc
```

It's close, but I don't see an mp3 stream. Also the [SAR 92:93 DAR 4:3] is different and I'm not sure how important.

Why is the mp3 audio track not included?

```
video:40522kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.310996%
```

Can someone please help me?

UPDATE:   WOW, I CAN'T BELIEVE I'M SAYING THIS, BUT VIDEO IS WORKING.

ffmpeg -i  -sn -c:a libmp3lame -ar 48000 -ab 128k -ac 2 -c:v libxvid -crf 24 -vtag DIVX -vf scale=640:480 -aspect 4:3 -mbd rd -flags +mv4+aic -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 30 -vb 1500k "41-redman.avi"

yes, that's my 41st try.   The video works, but no sound.  working on that next.

Comment: One of your examples uses `-an` which omits the audio track...

Comment: thanks. ya the last sample I provided in my update actually got it working